# Unit testing singleton pattern method __clone() in php

Tags: php, unit-testing, design-patterns, singleton, phpunit

I'm currently working on unit testing of a custom class I made, which is based on the `singleton` design pattern. Based on the code coverage report I have 95.45% of it covered. I am using `PHPUnit` to do the unit testing and I have been through [this article](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/882-Testing-Code-That-Uses-Singletons.html) 
 by Sebastian Bergmann.

The only problem I am left with is testing against class cloning throught the magic method `__clone()`. I have set that method as private to avoid instantiation

```
private final function __clone()
{}
```

What would be the best way to write a test to make sure that the singleton isn't "clonable". (The same test could eventually be used to test the `__constructor()`)

Not really a question but is it just me or the tests runs awfully slow on a windows box compared to a *nix box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call clone or constructor and check if excpetion has been thrown.

Comment: it worked using a reflextion class and a try/catch thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that code coverage is not a measure of how correct your program is, nor does 100% coverage mean you've executed every code path. For example, the ternary operator

```
a ? b : c
```

and compound boolean expressions

```
if (a < 1 || b > 6)
```

are counted as single statements even though you may execute only a portion of them due to short-circuiting. Also, omitting the braces around single-statement `if`, `while`, etc. blocks turns the whole thing into a single statement.

The following will appear as a single statement in the code coverage report so you can't tell if you've executed both cases (`true` and `false`).

```
if (...)
    foo();
```

I feel that

```
private final function __clone() { }
```

is too simple to fail. Testing that the method throws an exception (using reflection no less which your clients won't do) is testing the PHP interpreter--out of scope in my book.

[For the record, I too get a little OC when it comes to reaching 100% code coverage, but keeping the above facts in mind helps to alleviate it so I can move on to writing better code.]

Comment: Thank you for pointing these things out. I use code coverage in a "second layer" of unit testing, first I try to get all the possible cases covered with each paths tested and finally i check for code coverage, which might point out useless code (or redundant fallback that look clean but that have no use).